# What is the name of this tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, multilinear-algebra

A matrix **M** is usually called a *hollow* matrix if all of its diagonal elements are zero:

$$ M_{pp} = 0, \quad \forall \: p.
$$

We can generalize this to an $n$-way tensor **T**, such that:

$$ T_{p_1 \cdots p_n} = 0, \quad \mbox{if $p_i = p_j$ for some $i \ne j$}.
$$

I call these types of tensors *hollow*. Are there other names for these?

Edit: made the question more precise.

Comment: Do you mean an element is zero if *all* indices $p_i$ are equal, or if at least *two* of them are equal?

Comment: At least two of them are equal.

Comment: a special case, if it is also antisymmetric under exchange of any two indices, is called a completely antisymmetric tensor.

Comment: This hollow condition is not invariant under conjugation by a linear transformation, so it doesn't seem very natural to me; it is basis dependent. It would be nice if you could include a sentence explaining where it might naturally arise, or why it is important.

Comment: 1. It may occur in many-fermion wavefunctions due to the Pauli exclusion principle. Usually, it is also antisymmetric as @CarloBeenakker pointed out.

Comment: 2. If the non-zero elements are all 1, then the tensor represents an elementary symmetric polynomial.